# What the probabilty of selecting different congruences of numbers?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, number-theory

I was reading through an article the other day regarding the probability of selecting relatively prime integers, which is known to be $\frac{6}{\pi^2}$. How would you compute the probability of randomly selecting 2 integers, call them *x* and *y* such that x is congruent to 0 modulo 4, whereas, y is congruent to 1 modulo 4.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is much easier than the probability of relatively prime that you mention, although there's a little ambiguity in the problem description.

Choosing from all integers, the probabilities for $x$ and $y$ are independent and the probability for each remainder modulo 4 is 1/4.  So
$$ P(x \equiv 0 \bmod 4 \; \& \; y \equiv 1 \bmod 4) = P(x \equiv 0 \bmod 4) \cdot P(y \equiv 1 \bmod 4) = \left(\frac{1}{4}\right)^2 = \frac{1}{16}.$$

If you mean, though, the probability of selecting two numbers where one (call it $x$) is congruent to 0 modulo 4 and the other (call it $y$) is congruent to 1 modulo 4, then the probability is doubled to $1/8$ since the two numbers could be chosen in either order.  (Compare the probability of rolling a 3 with two 6-sided dice.)

Comment: Thanks, Brian. I might have just been thinking about this problem too hard. This gives me a few thoughts. I running through various simulations, and I keep running into a lower bound of approx 1/3. It might be due to the fact that the numbers are not independently selected.